# Ubuntu 13,04 AMD processor overheating

Tags: 13.04, ati, asus, overheating

Hi I have an Asus Eee PC seashell series 1215B with an AMD E-350 Processor (2CPUs)-1.6GHz, and after installing Ubuntu 13.04 it keeps getting hot to the point that the laptop turns off alone. I do not have this problem with windows, and when I had ubuntu 12.04 LTS my computer would get up to 91°C, so why is my PC getting so hot with ubuntu?? I do not own an external cooling fan because I thought it would not be necessary but it seems that it is a must if I want to use ubuntu... What can I do??

P.S. I am not the only person I know to have this issue, many of my friends went back to windows because of this :S

Comment: See [the answers to this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter) and try the solutions. If this does not work, edit your question with the new information.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run powertop to investigate where energy is used most. U can also use optimize option to see it produces less heath. But for permanent setting there is some work to do. pls google powertop.

```
sudo apt-get install powertop
```

Also install tlp as follows: `sudo apt-get install tlp`.

or install the package by hand: https://launchpad.net/~linrunner/+archive/tlp
then `sudo tlp start`.